# Multiple histograms with title and mean as a line?

Tags: r, histogram, sapply

I'm struggeling with the histogram function in my exploratory analysis. I would like to run a couple of variables in my dataset through a histogram function and for each add the title and a line at the arithmetic mean. This is how far I've got (but the main title is still missing):

```
histo.abline <-function(x){

  hist(x)

  abline(v = mean(x, na.rm = TRUE), col = "blue", lwd = 4)}

sapply(dataset[c(7:10)], histo.abline)
```

I tried to add a main argument in the histogram function but it just doesn't pick the right variable name of my dataset vector. When I put `main=x` there, it says returns NULL for each variable. Colnames, names and other functions didn't work either. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to do it with ggplot:

```
library(ggplot)
histo.abline <-function(dataset,colnum){
  p<-ggplot(dataset,aes(dataset[,colnum]))+geom_histogram(bins=5,fill=I("blue"),col=I("red"), alpha=I(.2))+
    geom_vline(xintercept = mean(dataset[,colnum], na.rm = TRUE))+xlab(as.character(names(dataset)[colnum]))
  return(p)
}
```

since you have not provided data lets work with mtcars and create a list of histograms

```
dataset=mtcars
listOfHistograms<-lapply(3:7,function(x) histo.abline(dataset,x))
```

your list has 5 histograms that you can plot for instance the first by:

```
print(listOfHistograms[[1]])
```

[image]

More histogram options for ggplot here: https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-make-a-histogram-with-ggplot2/

hope this helps

**EDIT:** Multiple Plot in one graph

One way to do it is through cowplot library:

```
library(cowplot)
plot_grid(plotlist=listOfHistograms[1:4])
```

[image]

Comment: Hey Antonis,
you're great, it finally works!
Maybe, you also have a hint on how to integrate the par(mfrow=c(2, 2)) function so that I can see 4 histograms in one plot?
Best wishes and thanks again,
Karen

Comment: You can check updated answer with multiple histograms in one plot

Comment: Thank you, Antonis!

Comment: You're welcome Karen H. In case you found my answer helpful you may consider accepting it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Thanks!